# Can We Keep the Same Version Number in iTunes Connect on Release?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, versioning

I have an iOS app with version number 2.0.0 and build number 2.0.0. I found there is a bug in version 2.0.0 and I want to patch this and do a quick update. I do not want to increment the version number if possible because it is a small fix.

I have been working on Android for a while. Android allows keeping the versionName (a.k.a. version number on iOS) and just incrementing the versionCode (similar to build number on iOS)

Is it possible to release an iOS build with the same version number?
Would just incrementing the build number in the info.plist help me achieve what I wanted?

Comment: Possible duplicate?? -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/21125911/757503 To answer your question.. No you cannot submit an update to Apple with the same version number.

Comment: Six years after still not possible. Google play console no problem, primary is always versionCode  which is unique, user friendly version number I can use how many times I need just because of small changes (eg in app I forgot increase version number, so it has nothing to do wich code changes and I do not wont increase user friendly version number). Google play console is 100 times better and developer friendly than Apple's app store connect. In apple I can not change screens without release and increasing version number, also can not change primary language easily. In google no problem.

Comment: Awkward hack... I need to use e.g. `4.0.0` second time, but I can not in Apple so I replaced "0" with "O"  `4.O.O` Stupid Apple stupid solutions ;) Or another hack is to use dot char alternative: https://unicode-search.net/unicode-namesearch.pl?term=DOT

Answer (score 0):

If it is a small fix, then your version number can be something like 2.0.1  There is not a way which you could release the same version number and for many good reasons.  Lets say you have 2.0.0 in the store and it has a small bug, so you release 2.0.0 again to patch it.  About a week later, you are getting reports of the app crashing in version 2.0.0.  Which code base do you look at?

If it is a very small bug and not that important to fix, maybe it makes more sense to bundle it with a larger update later on instead of releasing a new update.

Comment: Wrong argument `Which code base do you look at?`. Both Google and Apple always refers primary with versionCode/build number which is unique, not just user friendly version name. Secondly I release two bundles in ech (depends on target android API) version in google but have identical user friendly version, but I know wich one bundle crashes thanks to versionCode.