# iTunes Connect behaving strange after uploading new version

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

My app has two versions. `1.0(1.8)` and `2.0(1.0)`
For internal testers I need to switch to version `2.0(1.0)`

When I switch version to `2.0` and the build `1.0` fro that version and save. iTunes Connect warns me that the version `1.0` will be unavailable. I continue to `save`.

But after the processing the version switch back to 1.0 with a very previous build selected. I can't able to switch to version 2.0. Is there any known bug or am I doing something wrong?

**EDIT**

Ok one way to make the version change for internal testers is to make all other versions unavailable.

Moreover in External Testers when I try to add a new build I get the following error:

> This version can’t be tested because you have reached the maximum number of apps allowed for testing at once.

From documentation I see that one end user can have the same TestFlight account on no more than 10 devices. But how is this even concerned with the end user?

Comment: Please understand the question before down voting.

Answer (score -1):

The version of your app is `1.0(1.8)`. This means

- CFBundleShortVersionString: 1.0
- CFBundleVersion: 1.8

You need to increment CFBundleVersion on each iteration of alpha testing. So You should set CFBundleVersion larger than 1.8.

ref. [Which iOS app version/build number(s) MUST be incremented upon App Store release?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21125159/which-ios-app-version-build-numbers-must-be-incremented-upon-app-store-release/27521855#27521855)

Comment: the values are correct. i don't think this is related.