# Error ITMS-90062: The value for key CFBundleShortVersionString must contain a higher version than that of the previously approved version

Tags: app-store-connect, xcode7

I am trying to update my app for the first time and ran into this issue. I searched a lot but none of the solutions worked for me.

[image]

> App Store Connect Operation Error
>
> ERROR ITMS-90062: "This bundle is invalid. The value for key CFBundleShortVersionString [2020.0] in the Info.plist file must contain a higher version than that of the previously approved version [2020.0]. Please find more information about CFBundleShortVersionString at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/cfbundleshortversionstring"

And my info.plist file is :

[image]

General Window:

[image]

Comment: can this be the issue ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/37048170/569789

Answer (score 13):

TL;DR: If you have an app version that was approved for the official app store, you cannot upload a build with the same version to TestFlight.  You have to remove the app from official app store submission, or increase your TestFlight version #.

I figured out why this happened to me.

- I have an app in the app store with version 2010.
- I have been running an external beta test with version 2020, and build numbers in the range of 400-410
- In order to discover if my app would get rejected in the app store once I'm ready to actually release it in a few weeks, I submitted version 2020, build 407 for official app store review.  I expected it to be rejected for various reasons.  It was approved!  However, i'm not ready to release it since I still have more fixes I want to implement.  So, I let it sit there, waiting for me to do something with it.
- Then, I wanted to upload a newer build for my External beta, still version 2020, build 410, and I received this error.
- Thanks to user462990's answer, I realized that the error could be due to the fact that I have version 2020 currently approved and waiting to be launched into the official app store, so iTC didn't allow me to submit the same build # for a TestFlight external beta.

So, I selected "cancel this release" of the official approved version, and Viola!  I can now upload a build with the same build #.

Comment: In Xcode 9.2: 
`<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
 <string>n.n.n.</string>`, in `Info.plist` 
Appears in UI as: "Bundle Versions string, short"

Answer (score 2):

I think it was some issue on Apple's side. It resolved itself automatically after few hours.

Comment: Thx for mentioning that. After a year, I've learned that the service leaks a lot of errors that go away. Mentioning specific examples helps. For me, when you are trying to meet a deadline and you get an error, you want as much relevant info as possible.

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me is to change it from 1.0 (.6) to 1.1 (.0) It's not really a new "Version" but incremental improvements and corrections. One thought is that when an app is accepted into the iTunes store then next upload must be to a higher VERSION.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, this totally baffled me!

Answer (score 1):

You must always increase the version number when uploading updates, so change it from `1.0` to `1.1`.

Comment: I have as you can see in .plist file

Comment: @Bilal What shows in the Xcode's target *General* window?

Comment: @Bilal OK, I don't understand that.

Comment: Changing the "Version Number" (CFBundleShortVersionString) might solve the problem by over-kill, but the error seems to be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having a similar issue today. I uploaded a new build a couple days ago with no issues. I found someone who posted a similar issue here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7297092. They were able to resolve it by changing the Info.plist values in their sub-projects, however, I tried doing that, and I still ran into the same issue.

I cannot find any information on why this is occurring or when this started, but I know that I uploaded a prerelease build to TestFlight with all of the same projects 5 days ago.

I currently increment my prerelease builds this:

1.10 (1) -> CFBundleVersionShortString (CFBundleVersion)
1.10 (2)
...

I was up to 1.10 (7), which I deployed 5 days ago. Now, I can't get anything to work 1.10 (8), 1.10 (9), 1.10 (1.10), etc. They all say "CFBundleShortVersionString [1.0] must be greater than previously approved version [1.3]"

1.3 is correct as the previous version available in the store, but clearly, 1.0 as the Bundle version is not.

Comment: As interesting and insightful (and therefore useful) as this is, it's a comment, not an answer. I think you should simply add that it's a temporary issue with the Apple submission process, to turn it into an answer.

Comment: I posted the answer, but will comment here. Apple does not treat the version as a decimal number. They treat it as integers separated by periods.  In your case, your previous build is 1.10, which they interpret as major version 1, minor version 10.  Your new version is 1.3, which is major version 1, minor version 3. Since the existing minor version 10 is greater than 3 it will not meet their criteria. Try a new version of 1.30, or switch to their scheme and make your new version 1.11 (followed next by 1.12, etc).

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else dealing with this. My scenario was similar as follows:

NOTE: For my builds the version number is in the form of a.b.c (1.4.6 in this case) and the build number is just an integer (1555 in this case). Also, in general I use Fastlane to upload builds and I am writing my apps in Flutter.

I used Fastlane to upload a build of my app (1.4.6 1553) and submitted it for review. It was approved. In the mean time I found a bug so I rejected the release and removed it as per instructions above. Then I used Fastlane to upload another build (1.4.6 1555). This build was rejected with the ITMS-90062 error. So, I tried 1.4.7 1555, still rejected. So, I tried 1.5.0 1555, still rejected. Same error (ITMS-90062) every time.

The solution for me was to create an archive (1.4.7 1555) and upload it using XCode. Going this route was successful. ...and following on from there I can now also successfully upload using Fastlane again.

For some reason a Fastlane upload after a rejection (I assume either developer rejected OR apple rejected) will not work; you'll need to do an upload from within XCode to "fix" the issue and THEN Fastlane uploads will work again.

Comment: This is the only way how I was able to work around the ITMS-90062 issue and fastline. I have not uploaded using Xcode but rather I have used this command: 

`xcrun altool --upload-app --type ios --file <Path> --username <Username> --password <One-time-pass>`

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue when going from version 1.141 to version 1.15.  Apple does not treat the version as a decimal number - they treat it as multiple integers separated by periods.  Thus in my case Apple considered 1.141 to be Major version 1, Minor version 141 and then my new version was Major version 1, Minor version 15.  Since 141 > 15 it fails.

Two options to deal with this:

1. Use Apple's interpretation of version numbers, so you always increment the minor version by 1: `1.1, 1.2, ... 1.9, 1.10, 1.11`.
2. If you wish to use "hundreds" or "thousands" places (I do, as I try to encode the scope of the build in the precision - I use the thousands place for minor bug fix releases), then always pad them out with zeros: `1.10, 1.11, 1.20, 1.30`

So in my case I went from 1.141 to 1.150 and I was able to upload.