# Xcode7 archive upload to iTunes "ERROR ITMS-90049"

Tags: xcode

[image]

the bundle is invalid. the bundle identifier contains disallowed characters. see the section of the application programming guide entitled the application bundle

Comment: What is your bundle identifier when you get this error?

Comment: I have changed the project info.plist
Bundle identifier:$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)

Is this the wrong cause?

Comment: Same Here! I think it's an issue on apple's side, since I didn't change my bundle identifier at all and have submitted the bundle a lot of times in the last weeks.

Comment: I believe this is/was a temporary issue with Apple's Submission process.  [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33274537/error-itms-90062/33274581?noredirect=1#comment54350671_33274581) is a related question, where the OP declares the issue to be such. Please delete your question.

Comment: Actually this issue, which specifically is for ITMS-90049, is not at all solved yet.

Comment: ITMS-90049:I deleted the third-part SDK files(info.plist).It's go work.ths

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked all the info.plist files including third-part SDK files and changed the CFBundleVersion and CFBundleIdentifier especially in third-part SDKs then uploading succeeded!

Comment: yeah,I deleted the third-part  SDK files(info.plist).It's go work.ths

Comment: 补充一下,这个坑是UMSocial_Sdk_Extra_Frameworks--TencentOpenAPI--TencentOpenApi_IOS_Bundle.bundle--info.plist