# Application Loader ERROR ITMS-90062: The value for key CFBundleShortVersionString must contain a higher version

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval

I am trying to upload an update for an app on App Store using Application Loader. I am getting the following error.

> ERROR ITMS-90062: "This bundle is invalid. The value for key CFBundleShortVersionString [1.0.0] in the Info.plist file must contain a higher version than that of the previously approved version [1.0.0]."

I thought the CFBundleShortVersionString was allowed to remain the same, but the build number (or "Bundle Version/CFBundleVersion"), should increment on each build.

Is this because the version label (CFBundleShortVersionString) has to increment on each **approved** version? Meaning bug fix updates and such needs to bump the version label displayed in the App Store?

Comment: Please check here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933093/cfbundleversion-in-the-info-plist-upload-error

Comment: Thanks but my question relates to the CFBundleShortVersionString needing to be updated as stated by "Application Loader", not the CFBundleVersion (which I have bumped up, and I am using integers for build versions, so any wierd zero-stripping done by Apple should not apply).

Comment: can you show your previous bundle version

Comment: The currently approved app is version 1.0.0, build 5, iTunes Connect labels it as:1.0.0 (5). The version I am trying to upload is labeled in the organizer (by xcode) as 1.0.0 (7).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error ITMS-90062: The value for key CFBundleShortVersionString must contain a higher version than that of the previously approved version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33274537/error-itms-90062-the-value-for-key-cfbundleshortversionstring-must-contain-a-hi)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You don't need to change the CFBundleShortVersionString, the issue here is that your app is already approved, and it is in **"Pending Developer Release"** state.
Remove your app through **"cancel this release"** and try to upload again. It should work.

Comment: Sorry where cancel this release in xcode or itunes connect?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I tried to upload new version to my app. I did it with Expo. In app.json, it is necessary to upgrade in two areas.

-"version": "1.0.1",
-"buildNumber": "1.0.1"

and I wrote version 1.0.1 on the app store.