# Do I need to increment version number if I reject build

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

This post discusses when to increment version number:
[Which iOS app version/build number(s) MUST be incremented upon App Store release?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21125159/which-ios-app-version-build-numbers-must-be-incremented-upon-app-store-release/38009895)

Apples discussion here is not specific on when the version number needs to be incremented:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ReplacingYourAppWithANewVersion.html

That is, it is not clear if it has to change when they approve it for release, or when I actually release it.

My question is more specific.

Do I need to increment the version number if the build is in "pending developer release" status, then I subsequently reject the build?

Using specific sequence of events:

1. I submit an app with version = 1.0.0 and build = 1
2. That build gets approved and is in "pending developer release" status
3. I reject the build and remove the build associated with the release.
4. Can I submit a new build with version = 1.0.0 and build = 2?  (that is, leave the version number the same).

[EDIT] clarified version and build numbers.
[EDIT] clarify that my question is not answered by Apple's documentation.

Comment: Yes, you can increment the build to 1.0.0.2 and submit.

Comment: Apple's write up on versioning: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ReplacingYourAppWithANewVersion.html

Answer (score 10):

Every binary you submit must have a higher build number. Period. The version number only needs to be incremented once the app has been released to the store.

So in your case you can leave the version as 1.0.0 but you must change the build to 2 or whatever scheme you wish to use as long as the new build number is higher than the previous build.