# How do I get the user to submit the app version is the same

Tags: ios, facebook-analytics

The version of my App is 1.3.4.4349-xxxx.xxxx.

I use Facebook Analytics to record events.

In my Facebook Analytics page, review the user-submitted activity, and the version of the app submitted by the user is not the same.

In Facebook Analytics page not app store. My app version does not have a problem, but the user submits an event that contains the app version, most of which is submitted by 1.3.4, and the other part is submitted 4349, hoping they submit the same app version. Or can you tell me why they are not the same as the version of the app submitted?

#### I would like the user to submit the application version is 1.3.4, not 4349

### How do I get the user to submit the app version is the same?

Comment: just increase the build no, for e.g   build no = current build no + 1;

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik  I do not understand what you mean, what should i do?
4349 is build no, 1.3.4 is app version.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21125159/which-ios-app-version-build-numbers-must-be-incremented-upon-app-store-release

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik In Facebook Analytics page not app store.
My application version does not have a problem, but the user submits an event that contains the application version, most of which is submitted by 1.3.4, and the other part is submitted 4349, hoping they submit the same application version. 
Or can you tell me why they are not the same as the version of the application submitted?
Thank you